# Java best-practices/standards drawing practices

Tags: java, swing, graphics, standards, graphics2d

What is the best practice or standard for drawing graphics in java?
I have my Jframe with a Jpanel and a Class(foo) which contains a Polygon(shape).
If I want to display the classes shape should I call foo.draw(pass it the graphics2d and a few other things) and have it draw itself (which I think would be encapsulation? which I believe is preferred?) or do all the drawing within my drawScreen() method?

Thank you

Comment: What is the class Foo supposed to do?

Comment: I'm actually making asteroids and have mostly everything done but actual displaying. Foo would be an asteroid, but for the question I thought it was kinda irrelevant?

Comment: Ok. "have it draw itself" isn't really encapsulation, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle to me.

Comment: Thanks, would you advise I make another class to display the asteroid? If so, then should I move its collision detection outside of it also?

Comment: It's difficult to suggest classes without knowing details of the application, but you can take a look at Model-View-Controller pattern for such problems. If you decouple your objects well, it will help you extend/maintain the application in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Foo should never overlap with any other graphics, e.g. it is a Label or a Button, then it should definitely draw itself.  I suggest that it extend JComponent, implement paintComponent(), and be added using a LayoutManager etc. etc.

If the Foo can overlap with other graphics (say, it's some space game and the polygon is a quickly moving asteroid heading towards earth) then things get trickier.  I still think it best if the Foo knows how to draw itself to a Graphics, but you might not want to extend JComponent.

option 1: extend JComponent and implement paintComponent, but note in the javadocs that this is not a "real" JComponent and that it never gets added using a LayoutManager.  You can even change addNotify() to throw an exception to prevent this.

Option 2: have the Foo implement Icon - a nice little interface for lightweight drawings.

This still begs the question, something *else* needs to tell it to draw itself.  So something needs to keep a list of these JComponents or Icons and tell them to draw...